# Post request with arrays using python requests

Tags: python, php, post, python-requests

How can i create a post request like this with python requests?

```
$url = 'https://joinposter.com/api/incomingOrders.createIncomingOrder'
 . '?token=687409:4164553abf6a031302898da7800b59fb';

$incoming_order = [
    'spot_id'   => 1,
    'phone'     => '+380680000000',
    'products'  => [
        [
            'product_id' => 169,
            'count'      => 1
        ],
    ],
];

$data = sendRequest($url, 'post', $incoming_order);
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
payload = {'token': 687409:4164553abf6a031302898da7800b59fb,
                          'spot_id': 1, 'phone': '+380680000000', 'products': {'product_id': 169, 'count': 1}}

r = requests.post('https://joinposter.com/api/incomingOrders.createIncomingOrder', params=payload)
```

But it didn't work. Parameter 'products' is not created right. This is how the created URL looks like:
`https://joinposter.com/api/incomingOrders.createIncomingOrder?token=704698%3A8544082b36a413a51b5c8c3ce0e2b162&spot_id=1&phone=%2B380680000000&products=product_id&products=count`

So how can i create a post request with arrays of arrays in it?

Comment: HTTP is a text only protocol.  The most common way to convert non-strings into strings is by using `json.dumps(...)` which converts the dictionary into a text format.  It is then up to the server to convert it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try seperating your token and `incoming_order` into two attributes:

```
import requests

url = "https://joinposter.com/api/incomingOrders.createIncomingOrder"
params = {'token': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

incoming_order = {'spot_id': 1, 'phone': '+380680000000', 'products': {'product_id': 169, 'count': 1}}

r = requests.post(url=url, params=params, json=incoming_order)

print(r.status_code)
```

Replace the token with a valid token.

Comment: I was sending data=incoming_order and thanks for keeping the solution neat and clean.